# How do I scan only alphabetic characters into an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, character, alpha, alphabetic

I have a text file, and it is a paragraph with quotation marks, commas, periods, and spaces. I want my C program to scan only the letters into an array, while also making all of them lower case in the process. So if a text file said "Hello.", then the array would have: hello

Comment: Read characters. Take only the "correct" ones. Convert to lowercase if needed.

Comment: Say hello to the `switch` statement.

Comment: @tadman Why `switch`? `isalpha` + `tolower`. Done.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Periods and spaces? Wasn't sure if those would have special meaning or not.

Comment: Your program will feature these elements: `getchar()`, `if()`, `isalpha()`, `tolower()`, and `array[i++]`.  I leave it to you to combine these elements appropriately. :-)

Comment: Please show what you have tried. There are hundreds of SO questions along these lines, for you to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions. Two of the more "common" would be

1. Read *everything* into memory, then copy only the wanted characters to the main array while converting to lower-case.
2. Read character by character, saving only the characters you want to save while converting to lower-case.

Both of these solutions are basically the same, they only differ in the actual file-reading part.